# Google ReCaptcha - Displaying text images instead of food images

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

When clicking on the box is not enough and Google asks for extra user integration, it shows images to select/enter.

What I look for is asking to enter characters/number in text images rather than selection of pasta, meat, cake or other foods.

How can I do that? Because foods look very very unprofessional in work life.

**Want**:

[image]

**Don't want:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the research that I've done, there is no information to say otherwise. 
I did, however, found this [article](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.mx/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html) that explains a bit of the new «No Captcha ReCaptcha». Briefly explained, it is automatic, Google will decide weather you resolve a captcha or just click on the checkbox.

This said, I think it depends on the level of suspiciousness you are accused of by Google that you will be put through the respective type-of-captcha.